# combine GEOGRAPHY Points to GEOGRAPHY LINESTRING

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, geospatial, sql-server-2014

Is there an easy way to combine several GEOGRAPHY Points like this:

```
CREATE TABLE #Points
(
    Id INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    Point GEOGRAPHY
)
```

to a GEOGRAPHY LINESTRING in Sql Server 2014?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To combine two points you can do:

```
@Point1.STUnion(@Point2).STConvexHull()
```

To create lines, the points have to be in order, so stuff like ConvexHullAggregate doesn't work.  You might try writing a loop to combine them in order and then store the combination.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah loops are of course possible. However, I was more asking for  a set based approach.

Comment: Set based is more or less impossible for fairly straight forward reasons.

Think a set of points, (0,0), (1,1) (2,0) (3,1), these points are not in a straight line, more of a zigzag, but the line you want to draw may go from 0,0 to 2,0, then 3,1 then 1,1 as a kind of backwards "C" rather than the zigzag.

The points must be in order to make a line, which is why I suggested the loop.

Comment: Sure. The Id would define the order in my scenario. Just curious, why do you suggest the use of STConvexHull. IMHO this would only be necessary for polygons.

Comment: All I was getting at was that since sort is not considered in set operations, it was not really possible.  As for STConvexHull(), it is not in the documentation that I know of, but mathematically speaking, to make a polygon you have to have 3 points that are not in-line with each other, so if that condition is not fulfilled, STConvexHull will make a linestring, i.e. 2 points will make a line, 3 points that are in-line will make a line e.g. 0,1 0,2 0,3

Comment: @csetzkorn, Hey, I just figured out how to do this without using loops.  You can turn it into a series of short lines, and then use UnionAggregate to combine all of them - SELECT GEOGRAPHY::UnionAggregate(Line) FROM (SELECT Point.ShortestLineTo(LEAD(Point) OVER (ORDER BY ID)) AS 'Line' FROM Points) A

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to construct string from (x y) coordinates of the points (via point.StX() and point.StY()), concatenate them and build WKT string describing the linestring, then convert it to Geography type.

Answer (score 0):

I had a scenario where I had some points:

##### Points

| PathId | Step | PointGeo |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 0xE61... |
| 1 | 2 | 0xE61... |

I wanted to put them into the parent table (Path; a Path has many Points) as a linestring

##### Paths

| PathId | PathAsLineStringGeo |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | NULL |

I wrote an SQL that wrote an SQL:

```
  select
    concat(
      'update Paths set PathAsLineStringGeo = geography::STGeomFromText(''LINESTRING(',
      string_agg(cast(concat(PointGeo.Long, ' ', PointGeo.Lat) as varchar(max)), ' ') within group(order by Step),
      ')'', 4326) where PathId = ',
      PathId
    ) 

  from points
  group by pathid
```

<sub>The columns you'll need to adjust to make this relevant for your context are in PascalCase</sub>

This generated a bunch of update statements that I copied out of the results window and ran:

```
UPDATE Paths SET PathAsLineStringGeo = geography::STGeomFromText('LINESTRING(-1.22 3.44, 5.66 7.88)', 4326) where PathId = 1
UPDATE Paths SET PathAsLineStringGeo = geography::STGeomFromText('LINESTRING(-7.89 10.11 -12.13 14.15 -16.17 18.19)', 4326) where PathId = 2
```

There wouldn't be anything stopping you making this a typical updateable join though.. Perhaps something like:

```
update x
set somelinestringgeocolumn = geography::STGeomFromText(y.calculatedlinestringWKT, 4326)
from 

  parent_table x
  inner join 
  (
    select
      pathId,
      CONCAT(
        'LINESTRING(',
        string_agg(cast(concat(point.Long, ' ', point.Lat) as varchar(max)), ', ') within group(order by Step),
        ')'
      ) as calculatedlinestringWKT
    from child_table_with_points
  ) y
  ON x.pathid = y.pathid
```